Can I use Nearmap in leaflet via R?
I would like to know if it's possible to use Nearmap in leaflet via R?
If so, how can I do that?
I have access to Nearmap and can generate API key. I would like to use Nearmap as basemap.
I searched online but no information on that topic.

Welcome to SO, Agnieszka! Leaflet can render any custom basemap tiles that use the XYZ standard using the template leaflet() |> addTiles(urlTemplate = "https://{your_custom_url}/{z}/{x}/{y}.png"). Keep in mind you may have to pass your API key inside the URL template, e.g., ?api_key=YOURAPIKEY. For future reference, StackOverflow is not the best place for general questions about whether something is possible, but rather to help solve problems encountered when code is attempted. Please try adding some sample code (but don't share your real API key!).
